# How to use CloudConvert in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, cloudconvert

I am trying to insert API of CloudConvert but I didn't run it. I have got a 401 error.

I have a function that create a excel (.xlsx) but when I click this function, I want to convert to .pdf format. How can I do?

My codes: `

```
kontrat.on("click", function () {
                var sablon = butun_veriler.nesne.features[0].properties.kiralik_nesne_turu + "_kontrat";
                var sid = veri.features[0].properties.id;
                var rapor_url = kd_islemcisi.genel_url(gorunen_kullanici_adi, sablon, "v_kira_sozlesme", "sozlesme_id=" + sid, sid);
            
            // Dönüşüm işlemi için gereken verileri oluşturun
            const apiKey = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiY2U4ZjIzNTA5ODkwMGZhYWEzNjczZjc2YjEzOTQwMzk3ZGYzNGZkYTI5OWYxZTc2ODRlODdiNWRkOWI1YzBkNDlkNGM3MWYzZjBkNDExZDciLCJpYXQiOjE2OT'; //
            const apiUrl = 'https://api.cloudconvert.com/v2/convert';
        
            // Dönüşüm işlemi için gereken verileri oluşturun
            const requestData = {
                apikey: apiKey,
                inputformat: 'xlsx', // Girdi formatı (Excel)
                outputformat: 'pdf', // Çıktı formatı (PDF)
                file: rapor_url, // Excel dosyasının URL'si
            };
        
            // API isteği gönderin
            fetch(apiUrl, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(requestData),
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                // Dönüştürülen PDF dosyasının URL'sini alın
                console.log(data)
                const pdfUrl = data.data.url;
                
        
                // PDF dosyasını indirme bağlantısını oluşturun veya görüntüleyin
                window.open(pdfUrl, '_blank');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Dönüşüm hatası:', error);
            });
        });`
```